# Product of a set of functions with a set of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology

We consider two collections of things:

- a collection $X$ of elements, $X=\{x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots\}$
- a collection $F$ of applications of the form $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $F=\{f_{0}, f_{1}, f_{2}, \dots\}$

I am looking for the name of the operation that would consist in applying every application in $F$ to every element in $X$. It reminds me in a way of the cartesian product except that instead of just having:
$$ \{(x_{0}, f_{0}), \dots, (x_{i}, f_{j})\} $$
the functions are applied to the elements so that we end up with:
$$ \{y_{00}, \dots, y_{ij}\} $$

Is there a field of mathematics (set theory, category theory, ...) where an operation along this line would have been given a name and is associated to a particular terminology? And if so, what is it, and what is the correct mathematical way of looking at what I am trying to describe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a name for this concept, and I doubt it has a standard name. For a single function $f$, the set $f(X)=\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ is called the *image* of $X$ under $f$, so you could possibly call this the *joint image* of $X$ under the family of functions $F$.

A reasonable notation would be $F(X)$. But you should definitely explain what this notation means, since it is nonstandard!

Instead of giving it a name, you could just write what you have in mind in symbols. This is easy enough to do: $$F(X)=\{f(x)\mid f\in F, x\in X\}$$

Or you could write: $$F(X)=\bigcup_{f\in F} f(X)$$